# delete data on SQL table based on datatable input

Tags: c#, database, datatable

This method below goes into a table and deletes all of the table. But in the datatable  "table" below in the first column there are dates which i would like to be deleted from the database. how would i go about doing this

```
Datatable table = new DataTable()

    string sqlConnectionString =
                "Server = 100.720.8.196; Database = testDat; User Id = sa; Password = ";
                // Copy the DataTable to SQL Server
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString))
                {
                    string deleteSting =
                    "delete from dbo.testTable where clientId=1212";
                    conn.Open();
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(deleteSting, conn))
                    {
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    conn.Close();
                }
```

Comment: *dates which i would like to be deleted*, eh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm just guessing here, you probably mean to make the date column empty. If that's the case then you use UPDATE, like:

```
string updateString =
                    "UPDATE dbo.testTable SET datecol = @datecol where clientId=@clientID";

 conn.Open();
 using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(updateString, conn))
       {

         cmd.Parameters.Add("@datecol", SqlDbType.Date).Value = DbNull.Value;
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@clientID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 1212;

         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
       }
       conn.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are a few options. You could loop through your table and create a string containing your dates in a comma separated list. With that, you can create a SQL Statement like `delete from table where dateCol in (date1, date2, date3, etc...)`

Or you could just loop through your data table, and do one delete per loop iteration. Either way will work.

However you decide to proceed, make sure to use parameters instead of string concatenation to prevent issues like SQL Injections:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx